# jQuery UI easing duration probleme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

i'm trying to apply some effects to a div with jquery ui ,
the duration doesn't work ! always takes the default value .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-single-hide").click(function() {
        $('.menu-single').hide('slide' ,{easing: 'easeOutExpo'} ,1000 )
    });
});
```

Comment: The arguments are correct for *jQueryUI's* `.hide()` - works for me http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/uzxd2/

Comment: Which begs the question: are you sure jQueryUI is loaded correctly, so that you are not inadvertently using the jQuery form.

Comment: The code seems correct. Did you import jqueryui.js ?

Comment: thnax @AlexK. , your solution works :)